# Sumar una columna de un archivo txt en python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un problema tengo un archivo txt y necesito sumar la cantidad de productos de una columna de un bloc de notas

El programa que tengo es este:

```
 total = ""
    h = open("fact.txt","r")
    for x in h:
        linea = x.split(",")
        total += x[6]
    print(total)
```

Al ser un bloc de notas no estan separados por comas por eso el split.Si ejecuto esto me salen muchos numeros y no entiend porque si solo hay un print

Un ejemplo del archivo serie este, quiero sumar solo la cantidad

```
cod1    cod2    Fecha               Articulo   cantidad
1       1       2020-04-02 10:41:10 97         18   
2       2       2019-03-05 10:41:14 10         25
3       3       2018-02-10 10:41:07 20         12
4       4       2017-02-16 10:41:08 25         6
5       5       2016-01-13 10:41:09 30         3
```

Comment: Haz la prueba con un archivo pequeño (10 línea). Edita tu pregunta y agrega el archivo y los resultados obtenidos.

Comment: Primero que nada ahí está sumando x[6] en lugar de línea[6] por otro lado intenta hacer un Split con \t, tal vez no sean comas pero si un tab o una cantidad concreta de espacios

Comment: Además de los errores señalados por @fabran99, también tienes que convertir el dato a entero, pues de lo contrario estarás sumando cadenas. Tienes que hacer `total=0` y después en el bucle `total+=int(linea[-1])`  (-1 significa el último elemento)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, `total` es una variable numérica, por lo que debe ser inicializada con cero, no con una cadena vacía.

Segundo, debes descartar la primera línea leida, ya que trae sólo títulos.

Tercero, el valor se saca de `linea[5]`, no de `x[6]`. La variable `x` es una cadena (no una lista) que contiene toda la línea, y lo que estás recuperando es el séptimo caracter de esa línea.

Finalmente, `split` retorna cadenas. Para sumar valores, tienes que convertir la cadena usando `int`.

El programa corregido queda asi:

```
total = 0
h = open("fact.txt", "r")
h.readline()
for x in h:
    linea = x.split()
    total += int(linea[5])
print(total)
h.close()
```